# How can I use components in multiple files when adding React to a website?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have added the React files from CDN to my existing website, as described in [the React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html).

Is there any way I can store components in different files and reuse them? As one might using *import* statements (of course these are not supported in plain JS).

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
// ParentComponent.js

"use-strict";

import { ChildComponent } from "./ChildComponent"; // this causes an error

const e = React.createElement;

export class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
    child = e(ChildComponent, {}, "Some text to display")

    render() {
        return e("div", {}, child)
    }
}
```

and in a separate file,

```
// ChildComponent.js

"use-strict";

const e = React.createElement;

export class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return e("p", {}, props.children)
    }
}
```

For reference, if I use an import statement as below, I get a console error:

```
import ChildComponent from "./ChildComponent";
```

> SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module

Any way this can be achieved with minimal additional modules/frameworks/preprocessors?

Comment: how you import ?

Comment: @sinafarhadi I've updated the question to show an example

Comment: import { ChildComponent } from "./ChildComponent";

Comment: export ChildComponent with a default key ...... `export default class ChildComponent ....`

Comment: Both of these suggestions give the same syntax error, the *import* itself is not allowed in the file

Comment: is your `import` statement at the top of the `ParentComponent.js` file? (like right after the "use strict")

Comment: @AlwaysLearning yes, I've updated the parent example to show this

Comment: How are you using the `ParentComponent.js` component in project? Are you using some sort of module bundler like webpack or something else? e.g. for React if you are using CDN, it is via script tag

Comment: @Sunil using CDN script tag, `<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>`

Comment: What about `ParentComponent.js`? Is it also using `<script type="text/javascript" src="filepath/ParentComponent.js" />` or are you using some sort of module bundler (webpack)? If it is a script tag, covert it to `type="module"`

Comment: Add so I have to include every dependency JS file from the HTML as a module? No way to include a single JS and have it include its own dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

So to answer my own question, after much experimentation and searching, to include other JS files as 'imports', they must be included as `<script>` tags in the HTML:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script> <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="/components/ChildComponent.js"><script>
<script src="/components/ParentComponent.js"><script>
```

Or, just use a single JS file with multiple components.